# LazyColumn, how to add window insets padding to my padding?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a `LazyColumn` where I have a `contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)`

Now, I want to add navigation bar height to the bottom padding, as to achieve the "edge to edge" effect

so `contentPadding = WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues()`

But how do I add these two together?

i.e.

```
LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues() + PaddingValues(16.dp),
```

I created this

```
@Composable
operator fun PaddingValues.plus(paddingValues: PaddingValues): PaddingValues {
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    return PaddingValues(
        start = calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection) + paddingValues.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection),
        top = calculateTopPadding() + paddingValues.calculateTopPadding(),
        end = calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection) + paddingValues.calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
        bottom = calculateBottomPadding() + paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()
    )
}
```

But it feels wrong

Answer (score 3):

Prior to `.asPaddingValues()`, `WindowInsets` can be added to existing `WindowInsets` through the `WindowInsets.add()` extension function.

```
val padding: Dp = 16.dp

val contentPadding: PaddingValues = WindowInsets(
    left = padding,
    top = padding,
    right = padding,
    bottom = padding,
)
    .add(WindowInsets.navigationBars)
    .asPaddingValues()

LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = contentPadding,
    ...
)
```

Unfortunately, there is no convenient `WindowInsets` constructor analogous to `PaddingValues(all: Dp)` at this time. Google uses this convention in the [Now In Android](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) repository on this specific [line](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/7903f87dccba6f55bfef6919d068fa7d6ef1b31f/app-nia-catalog/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/niacatalog/ui/Catalog.kt#L62).